# How to convert '+' into + in Python

Tags: python, list, types

I'm willing to make a program that evaluates all possible combinations of operations ( + , - , * , / ) on a set of positive integers of length 6 (eg : [1, 6, 3, 9, 2, 9] ).

To do so, I am using the list

```py
symbols = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
```

and wrote a nested loop to create all possibilities

```py
+ + + + +
+ + + + -
.
.
.
/ / / / *
/ / / / /
```

by calling each row (eg : + - + * / ) a motif, and M the set of all motifs where

```py
M[0] = ['+', '+', '+', '+', '+']
M[1] = ['+', '+', '+', '+', '-']
```

and so on. My goal now would be to write a function

```py
evaluate_expression(motif, a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

that spits out the result of the expression
a motif[0] b motif[1] c motif[2] d motif[3] e motif[4] f

my idea was to try converting '+' into the symbol + but I couldn't find a way to do it, I hope some of you guys here would know how to do that, I'm open to any suggestion of modification to make this cleaner.

Comment: Given the motif ``+ * + * +``, do you want to evaluate ``((((a + b) * c) + d) * e) + f`` or ``a + (b * c) + (d * e) + f``?

Comment: Your question is similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: can `eval` be used `[eval('1{}6{}3{}9{}2{}9'.format(*i)) for i in itertools.product(['+', '-', '*', '/'], repeat=5)]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) library gives you functions for the basic operators (e.g. `add()`, `sub()`)

So, you could replace your `symbols = ['+', '-', '*', '/']` with:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
symbols = [add, sub, mul, truediv]
```

and now your motif-generating function should make lists of functions instead of lists of strings.

Then, assuming you have a `motif` list, as you call it (check out `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` for a function to generate all motifs), you can apply it by doing something like:

```
motif = [add, add, sub]
values = [5, 6, 7, 8]
 
result = values[0]
for i, current_func in enumerate(motif):
    result = current_func(result, value[i+1])

print(result)
```

Note: this method will *not* respect order of operations, it will apply the functions in order, left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Dictionary of function pointers seeems to be what you want to use.

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

operators = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}


def op(operator, a, b):
    return operators[operator](a, b)


print(op('+', 1, 2))
print(op('-', 1, 2))
```

In total, it could look like this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

operators = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}


def op(operator_list, param_list):
    assert len(operator_list)+1 == len(param_list)
    assert len(param_list) > 0
    res = param_list[0]
    for i in range(len(operator_list)):
        res = operators[operator_list[i]](res, param_list[i])
    return res


print(op(['+', '-'], [1, 2, 4]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute strings with `eval("...")`.

```
def evaluate_expression(operands, operators):
    assert len(operands)==len(operators)+1
    expression = str(operands[0])
    for idx, operator in enumerate(operators):
        expression += str(operator)+str(operands[idx+1])
    return eval(expression)
```

The function can be called like this `evaluate_expression([1,2,3,4,5],["+","-","+","-"])` and will calculate 1+2-3+4-5 = -1

Comment: did not downvote myself, but I can imagine that those who did didn't like the use of eval to cast strings to functions. It's a bit hacky, and given there are other ways to do it, your solution is not the recommended way.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a direct way to typecast a string to an operator (at least in the core python library) but what you could do is create the whole expression as a string and run `eval()` whiles passing it in.

```
opnd = [1, 6, 3, 9, 2]
oprt = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

def string_eval(operands,operators):
    final_string = ""
    for i in range(len(operands)):
        final_string += str(operands[i])
        if i < len(operators):
            final_string += str(operators[i])
    return eval(final_string)

print(string_eval(opnd,oprt))
```

Output `-6.5`